# I created a bot which have 3 commands. Invalid Form Body parent_id: Value "" is not snowflake

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

[image]

```js
[Shopify Sales Tracker/16:28:9]: [ERROR] ➜  uncaughtException => DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
parent_id: Value "" is not snowflake.
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Hp\Downloads\Shopify-Live-Sales-Tracker-doener\Shopify-Live-Sales-Tracker-doener\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Hp\Downloads\Shopify-Live-Sales-Tracker-doener\Shopify-Live-Sales-Tracker-doener\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async TextChannel.edit (C:\Users\Hp\Downloads\Shopify-Live-Sales-Tracker-doener\Shopify-Live-Sales-Tracker-doener\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\GuildChannel.js:336:21)
    at async Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\Hp\Downloads\Shopify-Live-Sales-Tracker-doener\Shopify-Live-Sales-Tracker-doener\src\client\commands\shopify\addshop.js:16:4)
    at async Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\Hp\Downloads\Shopify-Live-Sales-Tracker-doener\Shopify-Live-Sales-Tracker-doener\src\client\events\messageCreate.js:29:3)
```

```js
module.exports.run = async (app, client, message, args) => {
    const shop_url = args[0];

    if (!app.shopify.config.shops.includes(shop_url)) {
        const server = message.guild;

        var webhook;

        if (!app.shopify.config.webhooks[shop_url]) {
            const channel_name = app.config.discord.shop_channel_name(shop_url);

            const channel = await server.channels.create(channel_name, {
                type: 'text',
            });

            await channel.setParent(app.config.discord.products_category);

            webhook = await channel.createWebhook(shop_url);
        }

        await app.utils.shopify.addNewShopToConfig(
            shop_url,
            webhook ? webhook.url : undefined
        );

        const embed = app.utils.discord.createEmbed('info', {
            title: `Shop hinzugefügt [${shop_url}]`,
            description: `\`\`${shop_url}\`\` wurde erfolgreich zur Datenbank hinzugefügt.`,
        });

        await app.utils.shopify.loadProducts();

        return await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    } else {
        const embed = app.utils.discord.createEmbed('error', {
            description: 'Du hast diesen Shop bereits hinzugefügt',
        });

        return await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
};

module.exports.conf = {
    name: 'addshop',
    description: 'Füge einen Shop in die db hinzu',
    category: 'Shopify',

    owner: false,
    premium: false,
    admin: false,

    guild: true,
    dm: false,

    disabled: false,

    usage: ['addshop <url>'],
    example: ['addshop hoopsport.de'],

    aliases: ["add"],

    minArgs: 0,
    maxArgs: 0,
};
```

Comment: show us your addshop.js

Comment: Done, added above

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```js
            await channel.setParent(app.config.discord.products_category);
```

I see you use [this github repo](https://github.com/doener2323/Shopify-Live-Sales-Tracker/blob/doener/src/config/discord.js). So look what's on the src folder, config subfolder and discord.js file :

```js
        products_category: '', // create a category in your server and put its id inside here
```

Just create a category channel and copy it's id and paste it here and restart your bot.

Comment: The error speaks for itself.. the id you copy/pasted isn't a category id.. maybe it's a text or voice channel but not a category

Comment: If it fixed your problem, you can give my answer a checkmark to say it's the right answer :D